# finding common elements in list of lists

Tags: python

Struggling here... I have a list of lists like so:

```
In [272]: mylist
Out[272]:
[['ABC', 'NY', 'DFW', '1'],
 ['ABC', 'NY', 'DFW', '2'],
 ['ABC', 'NY', 'LAX', '2']]
```

I'm trying to match lines that have a common string in the 2nd element, so DFW in this case would match

So doing stuff like this provides the expected results:

```
In [273]: mylist[0][2] in mylist[1][2]
Out[273]: True

In [274]: mylist[0][2] in mylist[2][2]
Out[274]: False
```

but when I try to iterate though the list it doesn't make sense to me

```
In [275]: for line in mylist:
     ...:     if line[2] in line[2]:
     ...:         print(f"matched {line[2]}")
     ...:
matched DFW
matched DFW
matched LAX
```

I'd just like to end up printing out the two lines that match

Comment: Do you want to compare *all pairs* of lists? Or do you want to compare *each other* list to the *first* one? Or exactly what?

Comment: I want to compare each line in the list and see if element 2 matches

Comment: There is no such thing as "comparing each line". You can't just compare a thing; you have to compare it **to** something. What is the rule that says, for a given line, which other lines it is compared to?

Comment: ok...  I want to see if line[0][2] matches line[1][2]

Comment: What if there are more than 3 lists? What if a common value appears more than twice? What if there is more than one common value? What output would you expect exactly?

Comment: @Jeff OK, that's one iteration. What should the other iterations compare? BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood you but are you trying to do this?

```
mylist = [['ABC', 'NY', 'DFW', '1'],
 ['ABC', 'NY', 'DFW', '2'],
 ['ABC', 'NY', 'LAX', '2']]

for line in mylist:
    if line[2] == mylist[0][2]:
        print(f"matched {line[2]}")
```

output:

```
matched DFW
matched DFW
```